# I cannot find or click on this button using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I cannot find this element on the page. I get **element not visible Exception**, clickable messages. 
I've tried by id, name , css selector, any xpath alternatives or other ways I can reach this element

```
driver.findElement(saveBtn).click();
```

My html source code

```
a class="btn btn--primary" href="javascript:void(0);" name="save" id="saveBtn_24ad66f5be91c">Save</a>
```

Comment: plz paste source code as well and also your code

Comment: i put the HTML there before wasn't displaying sorry

Comment: plz try xpath like //*[@name='save'] ,also if not used then include implicitwait in your code as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems, time delay or element is not visible in current page. So you should focus the element before click.

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@name='save']")).click();